# Connecting NGINX container to a uWSGI container gives - 104: Connection reset by peer in the logs and 502 Bad Gateway in the browser

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am trying to get Nautobot running in containers with an NGINX front end container.
The Nautobot uWSGI server works fine, I can http (8080) & https (8443) to it and the server loads as expected.
When I https (443) to the NGINX container I get a 502 Bad gateway and I see this in the nginx logs:
`[error] 24#24: *3 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.254.80, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://192.168.16.3:8443", host: "192.168.254.19"`

I confirmed I can ping nautobot and curl https://nautobot:8443 from the nginx container.
Here's my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:8080
https = 0.0.0.0:8443,/opt/nautobot/nautobot.crt,/opt/nautobot/nautobot.key
strict = true
master = true
enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
single-interpreter = true
die-on-term = true
need-app = true
disable-logging = true
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true
http-keepalive = 1
processes = 3
listen = 128
buffer-size = 4096
```

Here's my NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nautobot.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nautobot.key;

    client_max_body_size 25m;

    # For subdirectory hosting, you'll want to toggle this (e.g. `/nautobot/`).
    # Don't forget to set `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` in your `nautobot_config.py` to match.
    # location /nautobot/ {
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  nautobot:8443;
        uwsgi_param Host $host;
        uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;

        # If you want subdirectory hosting, uncomment this. The path must match
        # the path of this location block (e.g. `/nautobot`). For NGINX the path
        # MUST NOT end with a trailing "/".
        # uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /nautobot;
    }

}

server {
    # Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

There are other containers in the docker-compose, but here's what it looks like for the uWSGI & NGINX services:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nautobot:
    image: "networktocode/nautobot:${NAUTOBOT_IMAGE:-1.4.5}-py${PYTHON_VER:-3.9}"
    env_file:
      - "local.env"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
  web:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nautobot-nginx
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - "nautobot"
```

Does anything look incorrect here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a certificate problem.
curl worked but only if I put -k to ignore the certificate error from using self-signed certificates.
I imported the uwsgi container's cert into nginx and it started working.